# setup ubuntu server for tomcat-apache,axis2,jdk

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver, apache-axis, ubuntu-12.04

I have to setup one server for following requirements:

```
jdk,
Apache-tomcat,
axis-2
```

Here i am getting following error:

```
Terminating connection listener    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener@73d2c4aa after 10retries in 0 seconds.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
   at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
   at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
   at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener.run(DefaultConnectionListener.java:80)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How can i resolve this error.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Your tomcat port/process are already running. try to kill them and restart again.

```
  ps -ef | grep java
```

command will give you running process related to java as keyword and you will find the process ID for the searched process. Then
you can kill process by process id (Ex - : 123456)

```
 kill -9 123456
```

You can [learn](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/) here